# SignInManager.PasswordSignIn is too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm running a website based on asp.net mvc 5. My website implements an authentication mechanism (email address with password). My database is stored in Azure SQL.

As part of my login method, I'm using this code:

```
// ...
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

This code line takes 35 seconds to be executed (!). This is too much... In the user experince, it seems like the web page is stuck.

I also tried the Non-Async code, also the same experience:

```
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: true);
```

*I found that* this slow behaviour is happening only on the **first login attempt**. On the second login attempt, it's very fast (<1 second). If you leave the website running for a while, it became slow again for the first login.

How to fix this and make it faster? What should I check?

Comment: So no one helped you with this? Did you manage to get it sorted?

Comment: Yes, I solved it. This was pretty long time ago. Not remember exactly what was the issue. But, this slow behavior happen because some SQL-User (built in in the system) that missing some critical access permission for some table. Once I granted the permissions, it was fast again.

Comment: It was definitely a permissions issue for us.