# SignInManager.PasswordSignIn slow on first attempt

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-membership

Using Azure website (Std tier) and site loads OK (set to be always on). Site/Code is optimized and pre-compiled.

First call to SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync is slow (2 to 5 seconds approx).

Log out and then in and pretty much instant.

Wait about a couple of hours and goes back to being slow (then fast after).

Behaviour is akin to something going to sleep or no longer loaded in memory.

Currently in test, so no-one else logging in but site (when live) won't be busy overnight so this would affect "first" user of the day.

code is:

```
SignInStatus result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Same/similar issue to [SignInManager.PasswordSignIn is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565241/signinmanager-passwordsignin-is-too-slow)

Comment: I would say this is a lazy loading problem.  To save resources, if a service has not been used before, it is not initialised (no dlls are loaded, no code is run) until it is first used.  Once it has been run, it will run at 'full speed'.  If the service has not been used for a while (configurable but potentially just a few minutes), the code will be unloaded and removed from memory.  This is why it is again slow after a couple of hours.

Comment: Try this.  Start your code locally and look at the output window.  Now watch what happens when you first access the site.  Look at all the DLLs being loaded and all the things that are happening in the output window.  Once that has completed, clear the output window and try it a second time.  See how much less is in the output window.

Comment: The site itself (in Azure) is set to Always On and the site/page loads fast, it's just the signinManager that's slow if not used for a while.

Comment: If SignInManager is the first thing that say, accesses the database, then there's a whole host of things outside of the control of the web site that needs to 'spin up'.

Comment: Locally it logs in faster on first attempt so hard to re-produce this issue. nothing in the Output seems to indicate an issue. i.e. running the PasswordSignInAsync has the same output regardless.

Comment: If you run locally are you connecting to the same database?

Comment: Yes, same database. I would also state that logins are in it's own membership database, nothing else (i.e. rest of site) uses it. Kept as out the box as possible.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still having this problem, I solved it by adding an index to the AspNetUsers table.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserName] ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]
(
    [UserName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```